# How can i set proxy with authentication in selenium chrome web driver using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium, proxy

I have  following script to visit a web page using python selenium Chrome driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
USERNAME = 'usename'
PASSWORD = 'pass'
proxies = ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
proxy_tpl ='{0}:{1}'
proxy = proxy_tpl.format(proxies[0],'xx') 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://{0}:{1}@whatismyipaddress.com".format(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
driver.close()
```

Chrome still asking username and password when i try to run script. How can i authenticate proxy server   from script ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75954249/20443541 does support that, as well dynamically

Answer (score 24):

Inspired by this this [solution in php](https://github.com/RobinDev/Selenium-Chrome-HTTP-Private-Proxy), i wrote a equivalent in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import zipfile

manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
            port: parseInt(XXXX)
          },
          bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "XXXXXXXXX",
            password: "XXXXXXXXX"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
"""


pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
    zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
    zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)

co = Options()
co.add_argument("--start-maximized")
co.add_extension(pluginfile)


driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver",  chrome_options=co)
driver.get("http://www.google.com.br")
```

In `background_js` string, replace the XXX with your information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this code. it worked. I am stuck at another place. I am trying to login myself using OAuth2.0 authentication and i am doing this on my localhost so I set localhost in my redirect_uri. But due to this proxy browser cannot access localhost. Can you suggest me sth to access the same.

Comment: i want to ask if {urls: ["< all_urls >"]}, needs any modification or works as it is. this is not clear to me.

Comment: @AbdulKhalid Did you try to put localhost explicitly in permissions?

Comment: @user3286105 what urls does it expect anyway?

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work if you start chrome in Incognito mode.

Comment: Work well... the only solution there is.

Comment: This works but I can't use `co.add_argument('headless')` I get `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension`

Comment: @hayj exactly. I want to start it in headless mode. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @SagunShrestha You can take a look at: https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/