# How to dynamically change proxies in chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem changing proxies, every time i load new page, it creates another browser process. I found solution for Firefox, but none for Chrome browser.

```
self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
self.options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
self.options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
self.options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % 'proxy')
```

Firefox solution: [Python Selenium Webdriver - Changing proxy settings on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776607/python-selenium-webdriver-changing-proxy-settings-on-the-fly)

Comment: Selenium browsers load the proxy per browser instance. I don't think you can have one window per proxy (i.e. more than one proxy in the containing browser object) if that is what you are asking?

Comment: yes, there is solution for Firefox browser, i updated my question with link

Comment: Hey @Viktor , Did you find the Solution?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in Java/Scala, I find that the ChromeOptions extends to MutableCapabilities, as the name suggests, is mutable, so I get the following code in scala, Java needs to change a little

```
val proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy()
val proxyStr = "127.0.0.1:1080"
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyStr)
val option = new ChromeOptions()
option.setProxy(proxy)
chromeDriver.getCapabilities.merge(option) // will change proxy used by the driver
```

Comment: That's neat, but would this translate to python?

Answer (score 2):

**Using [Selenium-Wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#switching-dynamically)**

I needed undetected chrome, but it's not needed.

```
>>> import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc
>>> chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
>>> driver = uc.Chrome(
...     options=chrome_options,
...     seleniumwire_options={}
... )
>>> driver.proxy = { 'https': 'https://IP:PORT'}
>>> driver.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
>>> driver.proxy = { }
>>> driver.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
```

It does take about 5 seconds though, but works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Once chrome instance is launched, you can't change the proxy, as the changes to capabilities have no effect. But there is a workaround to the issue. You have to use a local proxy, which will target the parent proxies(your desired proxies). In this way you create the proxy chain. And when you want to change the target proxy, you just have to reconfigure the local one, so it targets the new server. Your chrome instance continue to communicate with the local one.

I'm using the [squid Cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/)

You set your target proxy like this

```sh
cache_peer PARENT_IP parent PARENT_PORT 0  no-query default login=USERNAME:PASSWORD connect-fail-limit=99999999  proxy-only
never_direct allow all
```

in squid's config

You have to script file modification every time, you want to set the new proxy. Afterward point squid to reread the configuration.

```sh
$ squid -d 0 -k reconfigure
```

---

I've wrote more in depth article to the problem:

https://dev.kit.eco/selenium-webdriver-for-chrome-how-to-change-the-proxy-at-runtime-a-workaround

Answer (score 0):

That's now possible using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles)

You can install it with `pip install selenium-profiles`.

It builds a **Chrome-Extension** which gets **remotely controlled** over **websockets** or optionally uses seleniumwire.

Example script:

```py
from selenium_profiles.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium_profiles.profiles import profiles

profile = profiles.Windows() # or .Android()

driver = Chrome(profile=profile, injector_options=True)

driver.profiles.proxy.set_single("http://user2:pass2@example_host.com:41149")

print(driver.profiles.proxy.proxy) # current proxy

driver.quit()  # Execute on the End!
```

Disclaimer: I am the author Selenium-Profiles

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
proxy.HttpProxy =
proxy.SslProxy = "127.0.0.1:3330";
options.Proxy = proxy;
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
var chromedriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

After investigated, I found the solution to dynamically change proxy with Chrome (work on selenium 3.141.0).
The key point is `start_session()` method. Each time when you requesting a new url, you could start a new session without starting a new browser.

```py
   proxy = get_new_proxy()     # x.x.x.x:y
   
   c = {
       "proxyType": "MANUAL",
       "httpProxy": proxy,
       "sslProxy": proxy
   }
   
   cap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
   cap['proxy'] = c
   driver.start_session(cap)
   try:
       b.get('https://whatismyip.com')
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

p.s. `selenium.webdriver.common.proxy.Proxy`.`add_to_capabilities()` may also be used when specifying proxy (so you do not need to use the `c` dict above.)