# Selenium Python Dynamic Proxy with Authentication

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, proxy

I'm tryin to create a bot in Python with Selenium which often has to change the proxy adress in order to do the requests. I've searched now for very long in the internet but I can't figure out how to set my code up so that I can change the proxy `host`, `port`, `username` and `password` without closing the webdriver and creating a new one.

I've already tried installing a custom Chrome Extension which set up a proxy connection from a background script with `chrome.proxy.settings.set` and entered the credentials via the `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener` method. This worked out for me but I wasn't able to change the proxy to whatever I wanted from my Python script.

Does anyone know how to set up a dynamic proxy with credentials for Selenium in Python? I don't care which Browser but the regedit variables for global proxy settings shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409418/how-to-rotate-selenium-webrowser-ip-address/59410739#59410739) discussion helps you?

Comment: @DebanjanB It's an interesting post but no. I'd like the program not have to restart the bot on every change of the proxy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change proxies in chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911913/how-to-dynamically-change-proxies-in-chrome-driver)