# How to update the Proxy Server within the same session using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, chrome-options

How is it possible to change the proxy server in **Selenium** after starting the driver?
I saw several threads on this topic, but none of the answers were correct.
You can use not only **Chrome** but also **Firefox**.

If you have any ideas on how to change the proxy when the driver is open, please write.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

Path = ChromeDriverManager().install()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--window-size=600,400')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas')
# options.add_argument('--no-zygote')
# options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--headless')

proxy_file = open("proxy.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore").readlines()
proxy = ((random.choice(proxy_file)).replace("\n", ""))
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(Path, options=options)

browser.get('https://google.com')
# Here the proxy should change
browser.get('https://google.com')
```

Comment: maybe you should use own local proxy server which can redirect to other random proxy - and then you could connect Selenium to your local proxy server and you could control it and change random proxy.

Comment: @furas I also thought about it, do you know how it can be implemented on ubuntu?

Comment: I never used local proxy server - only `Tor Network` installed with [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/) and which can be controled by `socket` or using [stem](https://pypi.org/project/stem/) ([Python: How to use Tor Network with requests to change IP?](https://blog.furas.pl/python-how-to-use-tor-network-with-requests-to-change-ip.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change proxies in chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911913/how-to-dynamically-change-proxies-in-chrome-driver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you won't be able to change the proxy server using *Selenium* after starting the driver and the *Browsing Context*.

When you configure an instance of a *ChromeDriver* with `ChromeOptions()` to span a new *Chrome Browsing Context* the configuration gets *baked* within the *chromedriver* executable which will persist for the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and being **uneditable**. So you can't modify/add any existing/new *configuration* through `ChromeOptions()` class to the *WebDriver* instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. ***Session ID***, ***Cookies***, ***UserAgent*** and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to `quit()` the existing *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of proxy configuration as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--window-size=600,400')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--headless')
urls_to_visit = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://stackoverflow.com/']
proxies = open("proxy.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore").readlines()
for i in range(0, len(urls_to_visit)):
    proxy = ((random.choice(proxies)).replace("\n", ""))
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(Path, options=options)
    browser.get("{}".format(urls_to_visit[i]))
    # perform the tasks
    driver.quit()
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to rotate Selenium webrowser IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59410739/7429447)

Comment: Hi dear @undetected Selenium what is content of proxy.txt.

Comment: You might update your answer according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75954249/20443541

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.