# Is it possible to dynamically change proxy while scraping in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a few codes that scrapes some websites running and working, but neither of that codes have a proxy setup. I tried some approaches over the internet to use public proxy to access websites, but my IP still being detected.

Is that possible to use a free proxy list without username and password authentication to make the requests? I'm currently using the *undetected-chromedriver* to do the tasks.

Thank you!

Comment: finding a specific proxy provider is really not in the scope of stackoverflow. you can try using [ToR](https://www.torproject.org/) which is controllable from python with [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change proxies in chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911913/how-to-dynamically-change-proxies-in-chrome-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

- "middle-proxy" (for example `seleniumwire`, see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72959568/20443541)) or
- using a remotely contolled extension (for example [Selenium-Injector](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Injector))